# Hovering effect in my table checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Hi I have checkbox in my table , when I hover my table row my checkbox appear. my question is how can I permanently display my checkbox when the user check the box

here's my html

```
table.md-table
    thead
      tr.md-table-headers-row.lr
        th.md-table-header.header_check_box
          md-checkbox.md-mr-0 ng-model="allSelected" ng-click="ctrl.toggleAll()" ng-hide="!ctrl.calculateChecked()"
        th.md-table-header.unit Unit
        th.md-table-header Product Description
        th.md-table-header Date of Expiration
        th.md-table-header Quantity
        th.md-table-header Discount
        th.md-table-header Unit Amount
        th.md-table-header Tax
        th.md-table-header Total Amount
    tbody
      tr.md-table-content-row class="DivForHoverItem" ng-repeat="invoice_detail in ctrl.invoice_details | orderBy: 'product.name'" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(230, 230, 230);"
        td.md-table-content.check_box
          md-checkbox.md-mr-0 type="checkbox" class="HiddenCheckBox-{{invoice_detail.id}}" ng-model="invoice_detail.checked"
        td.md-table-content.unit
          | {{ invoice_detail.product.unit}}
        td.md-table-content.product_name
          | {{ invoice_detail.remarks}}
        td.md-table-content
          | {{ invoice_detail.date_of_expiration | date: ' MMMM d, y' }}
        td.md-table-content
          | {{ invoice_detail.qty }}
        td.md-table-content
          | {{ invoice_detail.discount || 0 | number}}%
        td.md-table-content.unit_amount
          | {{ invoice_detail.unit_amount | number: 2}}
        td.md-table-content
          | {{ invoice_detail.product.tax_exempt == true? 'Tax Exempted':'Not Tax Exempted' }}
        td.md-table-content.amount
          | {{ invoice_detail.amount | number: 2 }}
```

here's my css

```
#HiddenCheckBox {
    display: none;
}
#DivForHoverItem:hover #HiddenCheckBox {
    display:block;
}
#HiddenCheckBox:checked {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) { }

Comment: Why not just give the rendered HTML?

Comment: `css` at Question renders expected result. _"my question is how can i permanently display my checkbox when the user check the box"_ What do you mean by "permanently"?

Comment: And what is `optionToggled()` ??

Comment: If you toggle the display on change... When your CSS already did, it may be your problem.

Comment: @guest271314 when the page run checkbox is display none when i hover the row table the checkbox appear and when i check the box and remove the cursor my checkbox will hide again

Comment: @wiwit Not using only `css` alone. `#HiddenCheckBox:checked {
    display:block;
}` is specific.

Comment: this is very tricky to me any idea??

Comment: There are no tricks. There must be `javascript` which also sets `display` of element. Using `css` alone renders expected result. You have not clarified what you mean by "permanent". Display `<input type="checkbox">` element when checked? If yes `javascript` is not necessary to meet requirement.

Comment: Look at what your function `optionToggled()` is...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette im sorry that was nothing i forget to erase

Comment: If your are sure that there is no JavaScript... Now! There was before since you pasted some code about it. So try to empty your browser cache and retry. Your question, as it is now, has no reproducible problem.

Comment: @wiwit _"here's my html"_ That is not an example of full and valid `html` at Question. Cannot reproduce issue described at OP https://jsfiddle.net/t8hnux5q/

Comment: im open for js code if that was your idea

Comment: @wiwit The `css` at your Question renders expected result, see linked jsfiddle. `javascript` is not necessary.

Comment: @guest271314 let me try that

Comment: @guest271314 try to use table not div

Comment: @wiwit _"try to use table not on div its not working in my table"_  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: not working in tr and td

Comment: @guest271314 nice sample

Comment: _"not working in tr and td"_ Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?

Comment: Are you using multiple times the same `id` on each rows? This could be a failure cause. Else... There is absolutely no difference on showing/hiding a checkbox in a `div` or in a table row.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes im usng ng-repeat

Comment: An `id` **MUST** be unique. Use classes instead. That is REAL basics...

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette my show and hide works perfectly

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette ok i will try to change my id to class

Comment: i change my id to class and give them a unique class and my show/hide is not working lol

Comment: Did you also changed `#` to `.` in your CSS ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes

Comment: i try this class="HiddenCheckBox-{{invoice_detail.id}}" its is equivalent to HiddenCheckBox-(invoice of id) that why css cant read my class

Comment: You'll have to post you RENDERED html... The whole table, then. Because... It is just impossible to find out like this.

Comment: ok i will update my post

Comment: You don't know what "rendered" means? In the code inpector, select the table and right-click "copy element".

Comment: i will rendered where???

Comment: Serious??? Okay... Do you have a live link then? I want to see the HTML code, not the Angular code that produces it.

Comment: i dont have will try to create jsfiddle

Comment: Hold on... I think I found.

Comment: give the rendered HTML!

Answer (score 0):

What is `{{invoice_detail.id}}` doing in the checkbox's `class` on this line:

```
md-checkbox.md-mr-0 type="checkbox" class="HiddenCheckBox-{{invoice_detail.id}}" ng-model="invoice_detail.checked"
    td.md-table-content.unit
```

Your CSS is defined to show or hide `.HiddenCheckBox`
*(you told me in comments... Even if you did not update it in your question)*

So if Angular produces classes like `HiddenCheckBox-345`, `HiddenCheckBox-346`, `HiddenCheckBox-347`... Do you think this could be your problem about CSS not working?

Comment: Id and class are references. By definition, ID must be unique (like your driver licence number) in the whole web page. And classes are used to references groups of elements. That is how it is.

Comment: So if you use a code which loops to produce 1253 rows in a table... Use class. AVOID ids in loops. If you use multiple times the same id, JavaScript will catch the first one and just stop the lookup there. And I don't know wHat CSS does with multiple same ID... But it fails too.

Comment: it really confuse me right now i try to remove my md just simple html and it work https://jsfiddle.net/gerome0123/v1zh8nkp/2/

Comment: There you go ;) ! Does it also work in your project?

Answer (score 0):

i update my css to this

```
md-checkbox.md-mr-0.HiddenCheckBox {
display: none;
}

tr.md-table-content-row.DivForHoverItem:hover md-checkbox.md-mr-0.HiddenCheckBox  {
display: block;
}


md-checkbox.md-mr-0.HiddenCheckBox.ng-valid.ng-dirty.ng-valid-parse.ng-touched.md-checked.ng-not-empty {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: ??? Why? It should work with your original CSS with `#` replaced by `.`

Comment: yeah it really confuse me but my senior programmer said always use class not id and i dont know why i just follow instruction

Comment: I think you are joking me right now. Just do as you did in your Fiddle. You know what your original problem was. Fix it before trying to create new ones by changing what is not needed to be.

Comment: i cant copy that the whole thing i dont know how to put rest api in my jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry, but I guess I can't help more than this. I'm not used to Angular or rest API more than that. I think I answered the issue about the checkbox not beeing affected by your CSS because or your use of ids. This clearly was a problem quite hard to find.

Comment: but your willing to help that was i need too thanks :)